# How to acess data from a MBO created from SAP using SUP

Tags: android, sup

i have been trying to use the generated Android code for a deployed MBO from a native android application.

the step  followed is as follows :

1. MBO created using a SAP BAPI ( BAPI_FLIGHT_GETLIST)
2. deployed it into the unwired server
3. generated the code
4. copied the code to a Android project
5. used the generated code to access the data from MBO using the following steps

   i)     Set application details

   ```
       Application app = Application.getInstance();

       app.setApplicationIdentifier("FlightSearch");

       app.setApplicationContext(<android context>);

       FlightSearchDB.setApplication(app);
   ```

   ii)  Set authentication credentials

   ```
       ConnectionProperties connProps = app.getConnectionProperties();

       LoginCredentials loginCredentials = new LoginCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);



       connProps.setLoginCredentials(loginCredentials);

       connProps.setServerName(HOST);

       connProps.setPortNumber(PORT);
   ```

   iii) register connection

   ```
      if (app.getRegistrationStatus() != RegistrationStatus.REGISTERED)

       {

           app.registerApplication(TIMEOUT);

       }

       else

       {

           app.startConnection(TIMEOUT);

       }
   ```

   iv) Set sync parameter

   ```
      ConnectionProfile profile = FlightSearchDB.getSynchronizationProfile();

       profile.setServerName(HOST);

       profile.setPortNumber(2480);

       profile.setNetworkProtocol("http,https");

       profile.setDomainName("default");

       profile.setAsyncReplay(true);

       profile.save();
   ```

   v) start sync

   ```
     FlightSearchDB.synchronize(new MySyncStatusListener());
   ```

i can see the status in objectSyncStatus() method of MySyncStatusListener.

initially it tried to upload data , since no local data is there for the first run it sends some null values and then wait for the ack from server. I get APPLICATION_SYNC_RECEIVING_UPLOAD_ACK status for  a long time and never get a ack from server hence data sync goes in to a dead lock.

In the mean time i tried to check the server logs and it shows :

2012-06-21 02:03:26.135 CONSOLE MMS pool-1-thread-18 - /registration/RegistrationServlet [com.sybase.sup.server.Console]6146

2012-06-21 02:03:25.491 CONSOLE MMS pool-1-thread-16 - /registration/RegistrationServlet [com.sybase.sup.server.Console]6038

If i disable the sync part of the code, i can run the following code but the result is always 0 which is obvious, since there will be no local data available without sync.

```
 vi) Access Database

       if(!FlightSearchDB.databaseExists()){

            FlightSearchDB.createDatabase();

        }

        FlightSearchDB.openConnection();



        GenericList<Flight> flights = Flight.findAll();
```

Can anybody let me know, if there is any issue with the code / configuration issue which i need to resolve to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with configuration.

i followed the example given in sup site. (http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-8803)
the problem was not with the code but the server configuration and the user profile that i was using in the emulator.

You can refer my post in (http://scn.sap.com/message/13405735#13405735) for the working code.